# AngularJS looping through http get req to find correct url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous

So I'm currently working on a project where I'm making a http request with angular to around 1500 URLs looking for the json that matches with the condition I have (only 1 of the URLs will match).  I currently have an implementation that sometimes work (but isnt deterministic I'm assuming because it the requests are asynchronous although it might just be a bug??). I'm still kinda new to angular so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly at all so I'm open to changing the code entirely!

```
this.matchingurl;
this.data;
this.findUrl = function(condition) {
  var that = this;
  for (var i = 0; i <= ; i++) {
    // this is just looping through the url list
    for (var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < urlList[i]['list'].length; j++) {
        this.url = 'http://' + urlList[i]['list'][j] + restofurl;
        var tempUrl = urlList[i]['list'][j];
        $http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
          if (condition is met in data) {
            that.matchingurl = tempUrl;
            return;
          }
        })
        .error(function(data){
          // error handling
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TLDR: matchingUrl isn't what I expect? Still goes inside the "condition" loop but doesn't spit out right url. Always gives me the same "url" for any sublist, right or wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use `$http.get()` if you already have the URL's in arrays and want to compare it to something? Also, can you show how your lists are structured?

Comment: @DanielB, he wants to compare the CONTENTS of the fetched data to something, not the url itself.

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but the way the question and code is phrased and named make it sound elsewise. Still, it would be nice to see the structure of the URL arrays.

Comment: the structure was basically

a list of json objects
name: ____, list: (list of urls from same site)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use `$q` promise of angularjs to do the task, either you can check one url at a time serially( slow if you ask me), or get all results at a time by requesting parallely. Below, I have done a crude implementation of the latter

```
this.findUrl = function(condition) {
    var urls =[], self = this, oUrl;   // collect all the urls
    urlList.forEach(function(list){
        list.forEach(function(url){
            oUrl.push(url);
            urls.push('http://' + url + restofurl);  // not sure where you are getting this restofurl from...
        });
    });

    $q.all(urls.map(function(url){
        return $http.get(url);  // returns promise for each url, thus mapping all urls to promise.
    })).then(function(datas){
        datas.some(function(data, i){
            if(data == condition){  // change as per requirement
                self.matchingurl = oUrl[i];
                return true;
            }
        })
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

same thing done checking one url at a time:

```
this.findUrl = function(condition) {
    var urls =[], self = this, oUrl;   // collect all the urls
    urlList.forEach(function(list){
        list.forEach(function(url){
            oUrl.push(url);
            urls.push('http://' + url + restofurl);  // not sure where you are getting this restofurl from...
        });
    });

    function check(i){
        function fail(){    // move to check the next url in the array
            i++;
            if(i<urls.length)   return check(i);
            console.log('none of the urls are matching');                
        }

        return http.get(urls[i]).then(function(data){
            if(data == condition){  // change as per requirement
                self.matchingurl = oUrl[i];
            }else{
                fail();
            }
        }).catch(fail);
    }
    check(0);   // start the chain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this you could run into trouble due to the synchronous `http` calls if you don't handle your variables correctly. Here is a snippet to achieve the same using synchronous `http` calls.

```js
this.matchingurl;
this.data;
this.findUrl = function(condition, i, j) {
        var that = this;
        this.url = 'http://' + urlList[i]['list'][j] + restofurl;
        var tempUrl = urlList[i]['list'][j];
        $http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
          if (condition is met in data) {
            that.matchingurl = tempUrl;
            return;
          }
          else{
            if(urlList[i]['list'].length > j + 1){
              j++;
            }
            else{
              if(urlList.length > i+1){
                i++;
                j=0;
              }
              else{
                return;
              }
            }
            this.findUrl(condition, i, j);
          }
        })
        .error(function(data){
          // error handling
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

this.findUrl(condition, 0, 0);
```